# Android: onTouchEvent start new activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, touch-event

I have been searching for a while now but can't find a working solution for my android code. Well at least one I am able to implement.

I have an activity (StartActivity) with a few animations. Then I have an onTouchEvent. This works fine to prompt a few more animations however after this I want to open a new Activity.

Here is my code:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start);

    RunAnimations(R.anim.translate1, R.anim.translate2);
}

public void RunAnimations(int t1, int t2) {
    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, t1);
    a.reset();
    Animation b = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, t2);
    b.reset();
    ImageView drop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.drop);
    ImageView iflush = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iflush);
    drop.clearAnimation();
    iflush.clearAnimation();
    drop.startAnimation(a);
    iflush.startAnimation(b);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        RunAnimations(R.anim.translate3, R.anim.translate4);
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

In the onTouchEvent, after calling RunAnimations, I want to start a new activity (TipActivity). That is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another activity to you `AndroidManifest` file like so:

```
<activity
    android:label="YourActivity"
    android:name=".YourActivity" >    
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="net.learn2develop.YourActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And then you could do something like (after calling `RunAnimations()`) :

```
startActivity(new Intent("net.learn2develop.YourActivity"));
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use that:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context, TipActivity.class);  
startActivity(intent);    
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.translate3, R.anim.translate4);
```

^-^